# Event system: GetInstanceDataEventArgs not firing

Tags: 2013, event-system

I'm trying to set a date-field of a new Component automatically when created, using the event system.

The approach is to set the field in the `GetInstanceDataEvent`

```
 public Events()
 {
     EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, GetInstanceDataEventArgs>(HandlerforComponentGetInstance, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
 }
```

And the function to update the field:

```
private void HandlerforComponentGetInstance(Component comp, GetInstanceDataEventArgs compGetIniEventArgs, EventPhases eventPhases)
{
    throw new Exception("-------THE EVENT IS TRIGGERED------------");
}
```

But the trace is never logged. I've tryed changing the eventphase to "initiated" but the result is the same. I restarted COM+ and the required services, and I've working other events perfectly, but this is never triggered when I create a new Component and select the Schema.

What is the correct use for this event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GetInstanceData` action/event is triggered on a `Schema`, not on a `Component`.

Comment: Right, using Schema despite Component does the job.